# Wordpress pages bug

Tags: wordpress

sorry for my English.
I have two pages:
page-test.php – insert record in database
page-laidiens.php – only print text
When I run page-laidiens.php  then I get printed text, and insered row in database! How is this possible? page-laidiens.php  executes own logic and logic in page-test.php. Wordpress theme: dynamix.

Comment: as you described it, it is not possible. are you sure the row isn't inserted before you run page-laidiens.php? Perhaps remove page-test.php and see if it still inserts it.

Answer (score 0):

Check what page *template* your current page view is using and where you have put your database logic (are you probably using a function twice?). Also, when using the dynamix theme, double check your timthumb component version and always use the newest one. The theme had a *few* vulnerabilities in the past.